# For closed $F\subset M$, there exists $\varphi : M\to \mathbb R$ s.t. $\varphi$ is smooth and $F=\varphi^{-1}(\{ 0 \})$.

Tags: manifolds, smooth-functions

Let $M$ be a manifold.

Show that for any closed set $F\subset M$, there exists $\varphi : M\to \mathbb R$ s.t. $\varphi$ is smooth and $F=\varphi^{-1}(\{ 0 \})$.

I think the function like this seems to work. ($\square$ is unknown yet.)

$\varphi(x)=\chi_{M\setminus F}\cdot \exp{\square}$, i.e., $\varphi(x)=\begin{cases} 0 &\mathrm{if} \ x\in F \\ \exp{\square}  &\mathrm{if}\ x\in M\setminus F \end{cases}$

Then, I can see $\varphi^{-1}(0)=F$, so I want to determine $\square$ s.t. $\varphi$ is smooth.

Am I on right track ? and if so, what kind of function is in $\square$ ?

Comment: **Hint :** Begin by proving the result in the case $M=\mathbb{R}^n$, and then use partition of unity to glue the pieces together.

Comment: I know this holds when $M=\mathbb R^n.$ But I don't know what you mean for the case $M$ is general manifold. Could you explain a little more detail ? What "glue the pieces together" means ? @TheSilverDoe

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity).